# Binding a button ItemTemplate to check in which row has been clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, itemtemplate

I have a gridview which has this look:

[image: First Look]

The Edit is the classic Edit/Update/Cancel buttonColumn.
The Upgrade is an ItemTemplate with a button integrated. After clicking one of the Upgrade/Downgrade buttons, the gridview gets this look:

[image: After Button Click]

Now, I have achieved so far to send the Save button event,in order to get the value of only one of the checkboxList (the one asocciated with the Save button). However, I would like to associate each Block of CheckboxList/Save button to a single Upgrade/Downgrade button. So, if I click the button on the first row, I need to disable the block on the second row and vice-versa. What i have right now is the following:

> In the Upgrade/Downgrade buttonClick:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.Columns[2].Visible = true;
        button2Clicked = true;
        Session["buttonClicked"] = button2Clicked;
    }
```

> In the Save buttonClick:

```
 protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        CheckBoxList chb = new CheckBoxList();
        Button bt3 = (Button)sender;

            chb = (CheckBoxList)bt3.FindControl("Checkbox1");

            if(chb.SelectedValue=="Upgrade")
                Response.Write("Upgrade");
            else if (chb.SelectedValue == "Downgrade")
                Response.Write("Downgrade");
                   else
                        Response.Write("Not Allowed!");


    }
```

> A second version of the Save buttonClick is the following:

```
 protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        CheckBoxList chb = new CheckBoxList();
        Button bt3 = (Button)sender;

            chb = (CheckBoxList)bt3.FindControl("Checkbox1");
            if ((bool)Session["buttonClicked"])
            {
                if (chb.SelectedValue == "Upgrade")
                    Response.Write("Upgrade");
                else if (chb.SelectedValue == "Downgrade")
                    Response.Write("Downgrade");
                else
                    Response.Write("Not Allowed!");
            }
            else { Response.Write("Wrong Button clicked!"); }


    }
```

It seems like the Up/Downgrade button click is not stored anywhere. Is it some event that I am missing?

Comment: FindControl looks at immediate children only. CheckBoxList is definitely not a child of a button. Assuming they are declared next to each other in markup, `bt3.Parent.FindControl("Checkbox1")` might work. However this all looks hacky, proper way would be to use RowCommand event

Comment: @Andrei it actually works, because the checkboxList and the Save button are declared at the same ItemTemplate. The problem I have is with the other button, which should enable only one of the CheckboxList/Save Button block. Do you have any example on RowCommand? And in which way you think this is hacky?

Comment: @Andrei thank you very much, some modifications on the RowCommand event, and everything is working perfectly. If you post this as an answer, I will mark it with great pleasure :)

Comment: There is nothing really to post as an answer from my side, I just gave a hint, that's all. However it would be super useful if you could post your solution as self answer and accept it

Answer (score 1):

So,
After @Andrei hint about using RowCommand Event and the tutorial found:
[here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/syedshakeer/rowcommand-event-in-gridview/) and [here(This is in both c# and VB)](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-GridView-RowCommand-event-on-Button-Click-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx) I modified my code as following:

> First, i modified the button like this:

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Upgrade/Downgrade" OnClick="Button2_Click" CommandName="Command" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>" />
```

[Use this tutorial to understand Container.DataItemIndex](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-ContainerDataItemIndex-property-in-ASPNet-GridView.aspx)

> Also, you have to add athe RowCommand event to Gridview like this:

```
     <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
     onrowcancelingedit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit"  OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand"
    onrowediting="GridView1_RowEditing" onrowupdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" 
    onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" EnableModelValidation="True" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical">
              <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
```

> And in code behind, here are the modifications:

```
 protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {


            if (e.CommandName == "Command")
            {
                //Determine the RowIndex of the Row whose Button was clicked.
                int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

                //Reference the GridView Row.
                GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[rowIndex];

                //Fetch value of CheckboxList.
                CheckBoxList chb = (row.FindControl("Checkbox1") as CheckBoxList);
                chb.Enabled = true;
            }

    }
```

It is as simple as it looks!

Comment: @Andrei i have to wait 48 hours :D. I decided to give the tutorial links, because in 10 tutorials, this 3 were the best ones at least for me